# Ubuntu cinnamon display settings doesn't run

Tags: cinnamon, display-manager

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04 with Cinnamon 4.4.8 desktop. Some time ago I started to have issues with my displays: they either aren't detected or the layout is reset to default one. I tried to access display manager from settings from terminal. This is the output after selecting display manager:

```
cinnamon-settings
True
Using pam module (python3-pampy)
Loading Display module
**
CinnamonDesktop:ERROR:../libcinnamon-desktop/gnome-rr-config.c:666:gnome_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gnome_rr_config_match (config, config))
Bail out! CinnamonDesktop:ERROR:../libcinnamon-desktop/gnome-rr-config.c:666:gnome_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gnome_rr_config_match (config, config))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any hints how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to run `cinnamon-control-center` ? Please also update your question to add the following output `dpkg -l | grep -i cinnamon` .

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reinstall desktop environment.
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon`